# Automatically running commands once Keycloak server is running

Tags: keycloak

I'm currently developing an application where I use keycloak to connect to an ldap server. I have some specific commands I want run once my server is up and running. For example, I want to run the following

```
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password password
./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

as I don't have https setup on the vm this is running on yet.

I'm building keycloak through a Dockerfile, however I've found that I can't just run the above commands with Docker as the server hasn't started by the time my Dockerfile completes running.

Is there any way to know when my keycloak server is up and running so that I can automate the above commands to run afterwards? Alternatively, can commands like the above be added to the standalone.xml file or some similar file so that I don't even have to worry about this issue? (Note there's other commands I also want to run so if it is possible to do through standalone.xml, a small explanation as to how it works might be of benefit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create init script and `RUN` from `Dockerfile`, 
the init script which starts the keycloak and then configures it.

we checked up-status of keycloak using below query in loop.

```
$ kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user testuser --password testpass
```

We setup testuser using `add-user-keycloak.sh` before starting the keycloak and removed at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's working as expected on localhost so thanks for that, however when I run it against my sandbox (close to production vm), I'm getting the same error where it doesn't know the server variable.  Should it be a similar process for this running keycloak against my sandbox? Note I'm running my keycloak server using "/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh & sleep 20 &&". Do you know if I have to tell this I'm not running against localhost and if so how? Thanks again

Comment: you can use standalone.sh -b 127.0.0.1 , where -b bind.address